# TensorFlow Dataset - how to make map function return multi columns as one tensor

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, map-function

## Question

How to write a map function that generates a TensorFlow dataset where each row is a multi column tensor?

## Problem

Here is a dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
    tf.constant([0.14375, 0.0437018, 0.97083336], dtype=np.float32),
    tf.constant([0.14583333, 0.24164525, 0.57916665], dtype=np.float32),
    tf.constant([0.6, 0.5244216, 0.8541667], dtype=np.float32),
])
for d in dataset:
    print(d)
-----
tf.Tensor([0.14375    0.0437018  0.97083336], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.14583333 0.24164525 0.57916665], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.6       0.5244216 0.8541667], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

### Expected Result

Apply `f` and get the expected dataset where each row of is a tensor of shape `(3,)`. Tensor of this shape is I need to achieve.

```
def f(x):
    return x * 2

for d in dataset.map(f):
    print(d)
-----
tf.Tensor([0.2875    0.0874036 1.9416667], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.29166666 0.4832905  1.1583333 ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1.2       1.0488431 1.7083334], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

### Unwanted Result

Need to make `g` return tensor of shape `(3,)`. Currently  `g` returns a dataset where each row is a tuple of tensors in shape `()`.

```
def g(x):
    return x[0], x[1] * 2, x[2] * 3

for d in dataset.map(g):
    print(d)
-----
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.14375>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0874036>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.9125001>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.14583333>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.4832905>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.7375>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.6>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0488431>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.5625>)
```

Trying to make `g` return tensor in shape `(3,)` but no luck.

Cannot use `tf.constant` as a return. Cannot use numpy inside tf graph/function, either.

```
def g(x):
    return tf.constant([x[0], x[1] * 2, x[2] * 3])

for d in dataset.map(g):
    print(d)
-----
...
TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead.
```

How can I fix `g` so that the applied result produces a dataset where each row is single tensor of shape `shape=(3,)` having all three float like:

```
tf.Tensor([0.2875    0.0874036 1.9416667], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

as in the Expected Result, Not having one tensor per each float value currently produced like:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.14375>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0874036>, ...
```

---

## Update

It looks I can use `flat_map` but apparently it is not efficient to wrap into extra list and unwrap with `flat_map`.

Not sure why I cannot achieve the same with `map`.

```
def g(x):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[x[0]*1, x[1]*2, x[2] * 3]])

for d in dataset.flat_map(g):
    print(d)
---
tf.Tensor([0.14375   0.0874036 2.9125001], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.14583333 0.4832905  1.7375    ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.6       1.0488431 2.5625   ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: In the expected outout section, the code runs. So, what's the issue you faced?

Comment: Hi @Innat, thanks for the follow up. ```g``` is the function I want to apply and make it generate the output like in the Expected Result, where all the float values as in one Tensor ```tf.Tensor([0.2875    0.0874036 1.9416667]```, NOT each float value has one Tensor <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.14375>, ...

Comment: Because the Model is expecting one Tensor as its input, not three.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `flat_map` is the way.

```
def g(x):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([x[0]*1, x[1]*2, x[2] * 3])

for d in dataset.flat_map(g):
    print(d)
---
tf.Tensor([0.14375   0.0874036 2.9125001], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.14583333 0.4832905  1.7375    ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.6       1.0488431 2.5625   ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```